# How to use RefTex search when search item contains special characters?

Tags: bibtex, characters, reftex

After hitting C-[ for entering a citation with RefTex, I want to search for an author that has an umlaut (\"u or ü) in the name.
Let's say the guy's name is Müller.
I tried

Muller

Müller

M\"uller

M{\"u}ller

{M\"uller}

M\"uller

and some others.

all with not a single result.
In the bibfile this author is entered as M{\"u}ller (sometimes M\"uller or {M\"uller})
The problem is that this name is very common and also variations of it (like M\"oller) so that just searching for M.ller is not helping.

Can anybody help? Thanks a lot,

Thomas

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm afraid it's not clear to me *which* document you're searching: a TeX input file, or the output file (likely in pdf format). Please clarify. It would be most helpful if you posted a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that, when compiled, contains the word "Müller". Please also be sure to indicate which program you use to view the output file as well as the program -- pdflatex, xelatex, pdflatex, or something else -- you use to compile the source code.

Comment: Hi, this has nothing to do with the compiled file. It's about the Reftex addition to the emacs editor which allows to browse the bibfile (AllMyPapers.bib) which is included via \bibliography{AllMyPapers.bib} to search for the publication you want to cite at the point where you called C-[ in emacs. The searching and browsing is all entirely text based and inside emacs. I tought that would be clear from tagging this question with reftex, sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the backslash with another backslash.  So, if your bib file contains `M{\"u}ller` you have to enter `M{\\"u}ller`, but since RefTeX performs (case-insensitive) regular expression search you can also use something like `m*u*ller`, `m*ller` or just `ller`, etc...

Remember that you can search in any field in the bib item, not just the author but also the bib key (if easier to type than the author), the title, the journal, the publisher, etc...

Comment: Works for me. Thought I tried that as well, but maybe not in combination with the {}.. Thanks!